# Obtain object and header simultaneously with spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, header

I am requesting a object to a external api service using `getForObject()` of the class `RestTemplate` and I will like to change the url for the service to also sent me a header with relevant information, I have been reading and found `headForHeaders()` with will return the header but will force me to make 2 calls to the service.

There is any way to be able to retrive the header data and the object in the same call?

Answer (score 0):

getForObject() does not support setting headers. You can use the exchange() method and pass headers. And then use `getBody()` method. You can also use `getForEntity()` which provides`getHeaders()` and `getBody()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented it using `getForEntity()` as already mentioned, I leave my particular solution in case is useful for someone.

```
HttpEntity<Object> responseEntity = new RestTemplate().getForEntity(url, Object.class);

HttpHeaders header = responseEntity.getHeaders();
String headInformation = header.getFirst("headerValue");

Object newObject = responseEntity.getBody();
```